# Error not letting letters in a field with JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a problem with my function, I am validating that you can not enter letters in the field the function works but halfway, when I stop writing the last letter leaves me this is my code.

[image]

This is my function

```
validateNumbers () {
    const patt = new RegExp ('/ ^ [0-9áéíóúüñ] * $ /');
    const pattReplace = new RegExp ('[^ 0-9áéíóúüñ] +');
    $ ('# NumeroUno'). On ('input', function (e) {
      if (! patt.test (this.value)) {
        this.value = this.value.replace (pattReplace, '');
      }
    });
  }
```

This is my html:

```
<div class = "form-group" * ngIf = "descriptionNumber">
    <label class = ""> Number </label>
    <span class = "textBigRed"> * </span>
    <input type = "text" class = "form-control" id = "NumeroUno" formControlName = "NumeroUno"
     (blur) = "ConcatenateAddress('num', contactFrom.controls.NumberUno.value)"
     (input) = "validateNumbers()" [attr.disabled] = "formBuscarLocked" />

    </div>
```

So concateno:

```
 ConcatenateAddress (field, formCampo) {
 if (field === 'via') {
   this.Via = formCampo.Abreviatura;
  } else if (field === 'num') {
   this.Number = formCampo;
  } else if (field === 'letter') {
   this.Letter = formCampo.Descripcion;
  } else if (field === 'numDos') {
   this.NumeroDos = formCampo;
  } else if (field === 'letter Two') {
   this.LetraDos = formCampo.Descripcion;
  } else if (field === 'card') {
   this.Cardinal = formCampo.Descripcion;
  } else if (field === 'numTres') {
   this.NumberTres = formCampo;
  } else if (field === 'inmu') {
   this.inmueble = formCampo.Descripcion;
  } else if (field === 'numFour') {
   this.NumberFour = formCampo;
  }
}
```

and so I show it:

```
<div class = "col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" [hidden] = "hideAddress">
    <div class = "col-xs-12 col-md-12 col-lg-12" style = "padding-bottom: 15px">
        <label class = "textBlod"> Selected address: & nbsp; </label>
           <span>
                {{Via}} {{Number}} {{Letter}} {{NumeroDos}} {{LetraDos}} {{Cardinal}} {{NumeroTres}} {{property}}
                 {{Number four}}
             </ span>
     </div>
</div>
```

What am I doing wrong ? Or is there another way to do it?

Comment: I suspect event order. You can try a `setTimeOut()` to ensure that the variable has had time to change before using it, or combine both functions into one that runs in sequence, or change which events you are using - instead of blur perhaps `(ngModelChange)`

Comment: You were right, you can publish a response of more or less how to change the order or why I have to change the events to give acepatada the question @tanques